# periodically search with gmailr

Tags: email, gmail, full-text-search, periodicity

I would like to periodically search my gmail inbox by specific e-mails with a fixed subject. Someone have any idea how can I automate this search? I'm using the gmailr package. Any idea would be much appreciated.

Best regards,
Hellen

Comment: jimhester made a successful suggestion on the https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr where I also asked the question (periodically search my gmail inbox #103).

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution using AWS. I wrote about it in detail [here](http://boazsobrado.com/blog/2018/11/08/a-smart-email--sms-bot-on-aws-using-r/).

Briefly, what you need to do is:

1. Set up an AWS instance.
2. Write a function to check email. My function below.
3. Set up a CronR job to run it regularly.

   ```
   checkEmail <- function(searchString="from: X@example.com [Test]: New Order",minutesThreshold=20){

     searchResults<- messages(searchString) %>% 
       unlist(.,recursive = FALSE)

     cat(
       paste0(
         searchResults$resultSizeEstimate," results found for ",searchString,"\n"))

     # extract bookings
     searchResultsDf <- dplyr::bind_rows(searchResults$messages)

     selectid <- vector()

     for(i in 1:nrow(searchResultsDf)){
       # get individual ID  
       id <- searchResultsDf$id[i]
       #extract message
       resultMessage <- message(id, format = "full")
       # Get the time received of the message
       timeReceived <- resultMessage$internalDate %>%
         as.numeric() %>% 
         `/`(1000) %>%
         as.POSIXct(origin= "1970-01-01")

       cat(paste0("Message received at ",timeReceived,"\n"))

       # if it was a long time ago ignore
       if(
         (timeReceived) < (Sys.time()-minutesThreshold*60)
       ){
         cat("No recent messages found \n")
         break
       }else{
         selectid[i] <- id
       }
     }
     return(selectid)
   }
   ```